# How to pass comment object to reply form in django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python-3.x, django

I can't find a way to pass comment model to a jQuery reply form.  Code on github:  [github](https://github.com/dungnguyen1991/comment). Snippet code is below.

I have two models:

```
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

class Comment(models.Model):
    user        = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content     = models.TextField()
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class Reply(models.Model):
    user        = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment     = models.ForeignKey(Comment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content     = models.TextField()
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I create reply form by jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $form = $('<form class="mt-3" method="POST" action="/reply/"></form>');
    $form.append("<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='" + csrftoken + "'>");
    $form.append('<textarea name="content" id="" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>');
    $form.append('<br />');
    $form.append('<input type="button" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-dark me-2 remove-button">');
    $form.append('<input type="submit" value="Post" class="btn btn-primary">');
    $(".reply-button").click(function(){
        $button = $(this);
        $button.parent().append($form);
    });

    //gán sự kiện khi sử dụng append một đối tượng sau này
    $(document).on('click', '.remove-button', function(){ 
        $form.remove();
    });
})
```

Action redirect to ReplyView view:

```
class ReplyView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # I expect something can get Comment id for reply
        qs = Comment.objects.filter(id = 1)
        comment = qs.first()
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            r = Reply(user = request.user, comment = comment, content= request.POST.get("content"))
            r.save()
        return redirect("comment-page")
```

Comment: console.log button or form.  is there an error?

Comment: I am not sure about your question, but The form for reply has not error. I have not way for reply apply correct comment. For example, if you reply for comment with id = 1, I expect a new reply at the end of comment with id =1

Comment: I have resolved with hidden input element.